What are the most common types of FOD (Foreign Object Debris)?
Would like to know what are the 2 most common types of FOD.
More specifically would like to know which ones causes the most incidents/accidents.

I think the answer to this question varies quite a bit from airport to airport and area to area. Runway FOD is usually of different nature (stones, dead animals) than Apron FOD. Of course one could aggregate all FOD data worldwide, but what would the benefit be?

I understand your point. I'm just curious, actually more specifically which FOD causes the most incidents/accidents. Updating post.

I think the answer to this question varies quite a bit from airport to airport (and aircraft carriers) and from operation area to operation area. Runway FOD is will be of different nature (rubber chunks, stones, dead animals ) than Apron FOD (plastic bags, luggage tags, soda cans).
The following is quoted from the FAA's Advisory Circular AC-150-5210-24

c. FOD Taxonomy.  The exact nature of FOD is also varied.  FOD can be composed of any material and can be of any color and size.  In a one year airport study (Information Paper on French Study on Automatic FOD Detection Systems – Workshop EUROCONTROL, 9-10 June 2008), over 60% of the collected, known FOD items were made of metal, followed by 18% of the items being made of rubber.  Dark-colored items made up nearly 50% of the FOD collected.  Typical FOD includes the following:

aircraft and engine fasteners (nuts, bolts, washers, safety wire, etc.);
aircraft parts (fuel caps, landing gear fragments, oil sticks, metal sheets, trapdoors, and tire fragments);
mechanics' tools;
catering supplies;
flight line items (nails, personnel badges, pens, pencils, luggage tags, soda cans, etc.);
apron items (paper and plastic debris from catering and freight pallets, luggage parts, and debris from ramp equipment);
runway and taxiway materials (concrete and asphalt chunks, rubber joint materials, and paint chips);
construction debris (pieces of wood, stones, fasteners and miscellaneous metal objects);
plastic and/or polyethylene materials; - natural materials (plant fragments, wildlife and volcanic ash); and
contaminants from winter conditions (snow, ice).

FOD removal operations are not meant to occur when a given area is contaminated with snow or ice.  In such winter conditions, the procedures listed in AC 150/5200-30, Airport Winter Safety and Operations, are used to clear the AOA surfaces.


Around the ramp area near the gates, it's zipper tags everywhere.

One possible answer is that the most common FOD is unknown! A 1998 study on US Air Force FOD prevention practices and procedures included a review of DoD statistics on sources and root causes, in conjunction with the rest of the study. What they found is probably similar to the civilian world (page 3, emphasis mine):

For the study, data on DoD FOD incidents was obtained from the Air Force Safety Center and the Naval Safety Center. This data, while useful in providing a background on the types of FOD incidents, did not lend itself to extensive statistical analysis. There were three reasons for this: 1) Some of the information held by these organizations is classified and cannot be released, which led to an incomplete data set for analysis. 2) Different military units collect, track and report different types of information. What is considered a FOD incident in the Air Force's Air Combat Command is not necessarily the same thing as a FOD incident in the Navy, or even in other Air Force Major Commands. 3) While all FOD incidents are investigated, the root cause of the incident is never determined in many cases (almost 50%)."

If half of the incidents didn't have a root cause identified, a source of FOD which is harder to identify in an incident will likely be deeply undercounted, making the tallying up of the remainder a potentially poor guide to what, in total, was out there causing problems.
